# Removing outliers in R plot function

Tags: r, regression, outliers

I'm trying to do a scatterplot in R and would love to remove an outlier I've already identified.

My plot function:

```
attach(L)
plot(independent variable, dependent variable, main="TITLE", xlab="x-axis label", ylab="y-axis label", pch=18, col="blue")
text(independent variable, dependent variable, data label, cex=0.6, pos=4, col="red")
```

My best-fit line:

```
abline(lm(dependent variable ~ independent variable))
```

Is there a simple way I can remove "ISR" on the graph below without installing any additional packages? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic in here. If you are interested in outliers check already existing answers on [tag:outliers]. Notice however that if you want to remove them *only* for plotting purpose, then the only thing that is really needed in here is to adjust your y-axis range not to include certain values...

Answer (score 2):

1) If you just want to exclude $y$ values above (or below) some specific value, use the `ylim` argument to plot. e.g. `,ylim=c(0,20)` should work for the above plot.

2) You say you've already "identified" the outliers. If you have a logical variable or expression that indicates the outliers, you can use that in your plot.

e.g. consider:

```
 # let's make a small data example
 x=1:10
 y=rnorm(10)
 y[5]=30
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))

 plot(x,y)  # outlier problem
 yout=y>5   # some logical rule for identifying an outlier
 plot(x[!yout],y[!yout])  # toss them out
```

[image]